# regularization with customized training in tf.keras (TF2.0)

Tags: tensorflow2.0

I have a keras model with regularization initialized with kernel_regularizer. In the customized training loop, where GradientTape is used, does optimizer.apply_gradients applies regularization loss automatically? if not, the following code shows an implementation, is that a good way to apply regularization? Am I doing the right way?

```
def GetModel():
    inputs = Input(shape=(784,), name='digits')
    x = Dense(64, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(1e-4))(inputs)
    x = Dense(64, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(1e-4))(x)
    outputs = Dense(10, name='predictions')(x)
    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
    return model

mymodel = GetModel()

@tf.function
def train_step(x, y_true, optimizer):   
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        y_pred = mymodel(x, training=True)
        loss_training = my_custom_loss_function(y_true, y_pred)
        loss_regularization = tf.math.add_n(mymodel.losses)
        loss_total = loss_training + loss_regularization

    gradients = tape.gradient(loss_total, mymodel.trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, mymodel.trainable_variables))
    return loss_total
```

Comment: this is the right way, reference: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/overfit_and_underfit

Comment: Just in case this matters to anyone, it is important to not only calculate, but also sum `loss_training` and `loss_regularization` inside the `tape` block, otherwise the gradients won't be computed.